# How to insert past the last letter of a line

Tags: vim, vi

many times I'll want to enter insert mode but after the last character on a given line:

for example:

```
    some code {
               ^ <- want to insert here
```

I can't move past the `{` in normal mode. The closet command I can find so far is `o` which inserts on a new line.

(*EDIT* sorry for the initial erroneous title)

Comment: Any decent vim tutorial covers that. This post does not show any research effort.

Comment: Didn’t know I needed to provide “research effort”

Comment: If you do not bother to research before asking, why would a stranger waste their precious time on your casual question? Everyone's time is valuable. See also [WHYT](https://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: I did research, the tutorial I was following didn’t provide it and neither did subsequent searches, so here I am. I got my answer, thank you.

Comment: You should at least try the `:Tutor` command inside vim and finish it.

Comment: Noted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter insert mode with `a` instead of `i`.